# How to retrieve a list from another object that is in the list using stream

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have a little problem. From earlier steps I get this list:

```
List<Foo> fooList;
```

I need now get all id to separate list:

```
List<Integer> newListIds;
```

Is it possible to do it using streams, possibly as otherwise the easiest way to do it?

My clases:

```
public class Foo {

   List<Bar> barList;

   //getter, setter
} 

public class Bar {

   private Integer id;

   //geter, setter 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using flatMap:

```
fooList.stream()
           .map(foo -> foo.barList)
           .flatMap(List::stream)
           .map(bar -> bar.id)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or using method reference for getter and setter:

```
fooList.stream()
           .map(Foo::getBarList)
           .flatMap(List::stream)
           .map(Bar::getId)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Or `map(Foo::getBarList).flatMap(List::stream)`

Comment: Correct, will modify it!

Comment: Thanks a lot! @JDC, I spent some time to find a solution using stream, and it's so easy now :-)

Comment: Or just `.flatMap(foo -> foo.getBarList().stream())`, as there is no need to split that into two steps.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code:

List newListIds = new ArrayList ();

```
    for(Foo item : fooList){
       newListIds.addAll(item.barList.stream()
                               .map(Bar::GetId)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```